# wget: unrecognized option `--no-check-certificate' on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, unix-utils

Despite being advised to use `--no-check-certificate` option with wget, I get this error that the option is not recognized. What do I do?

`wget: unrecognized option '--no-check-certificate'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I've got a wrong version of `wget` compiled for windows.

> To support encrypted HTTP (HTTPS) downloads, Wget must be compiled with an external SSL library. ... If Wget is compiled without SSL support, none of these options are available.

This version is compiled with SSL https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

#### more reading

[wget manual - HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)